# Symfony2 get request in action called in twig

Tags: symfony, request, twig

I have a twig template with :

```
{% render controller('MyBundle:Default:leftside') %}
```

So i have an action leftside in my controller :

```
public function leftsideAction(Request $request)
```

I'm trying, in this action to retrieve GET parameters with :

```
$request->get('MY_PARAM')
```

But it's always empty, i think, because i render this action in my template, i can't retrieve all my request.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's totally expected due the concept of request stacks.

The `Request` supplied to "main" action is, well, `MASTER_REQUEST`, while those supplied via `render controller` tag are `SUBREQUEST`.

You can read more about `RequestStack` feature [**here**](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack).

Now, in order to have access parameters defined in `MASTER_REQUEST` you need to get `request_stack` service and then get the master request. After that, it's business as usual:

```
public function leftsideAction(Request $request){
    $stack = $this->get('request_stack');
    $master = $stack->getMasterRequest();

    $master->get('MY_PARAM'); // This should work
    $request->get('MY_PARAM'); // But this should not
}
```

Here is the definition of `RequestStack` class: [**link**](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RequestStack.html)